# Lazy regex matcher is in fact greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex

( code available at http://regexr.com/3a1sp )

I have this text

```
a.bcd.efg.hij = function () {
```

I want to get this

```
a.bcd.efg.hij = function hij() {
```

I try this substitution

```
"a.bcd.efg.hij = function () {"
   .replace( /\.(.+?) = function \(/, 
             ".$1 = function $1(" );
```

But the result is

```
a.bcd.efg.hij = function bcd.efg.hij() {
```

Shouldn't the ?  in `\.(.+?)` make the match non-greedy, i.e. it should match the shortes possible "." + something combination, i.e. the `.hij`? Why is it matching `.bcd.efg.hij`, isn't that the greedy match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this pattern instead:

```
"a.bcd.efg.hij = function () {"
   .replace(/([^\.]+) = function \(/, 
             "$1 = function $1(" );
```

Output: `"a.bcd.efg.hij = function hij() {"`

It effectively looks for everything except for the `.` which is what you are looking for in this case.

The problem is that the regex engine finds the first `.` and has a match. After that it stops looking.
To get it to work properly you need to add a pattern before the `.`:

```
"a.bcd.efg.hij = function () {"
   .replace( /(.*)\.(.+?) = function \(/, 
             "$1.$2 = function $2(" );
```

Comment: Yes, I should have said that in the original post - I am aware I could have done it that way (and indeed, that's how I did it). I just would like to know why my original one didn't work

Comment: @gotofritz: that's because the regex engine starts looks non-greedy only for the `.+?`. When looking for the dot it greedily searches for the first `.` it can find.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that regex engine always tries to find the left-most match (the match starting at the smallest index) before trying for a match at the next index. Since your pattern allows a match at index 1 `.bcd.efg.hij = function () {`, it will not bother to search ahead.

To solve this problem, you need to cause the regex to fail at every position before it finally arrives at `hij`. In this case, you can put a stronger restriction on what constitutes the name of a function:

```
/\.([A-Za-z0-9_$]+) = function \(/
```

You may want to allow the spacing to be flexible:

```
/\.([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\s*=\s*function\s*\(/
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand it, I can only pick an answer though, but judging buy your reputation you won't mind :-)